# Create post-event forms in Cognito allowing users to see what they entered in pre-event

Tags: cognito-forms

We want to launch a form for an event where each participant has to fill in some individual information (input field) before the event. This individual information needs to be displayed to each participant again after the event (to reflect about it). Additionally more questions will display after the event.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms. We are currently working on a feature that will allow you to share entries. This feature will include support for including a link to view or edit an entry post submission on the confirmation page or in the confirmation email. For your example, a user will submit the form to register for the event, and then use the link included in the confirmation page or in the confirmation email to update their entry to provide feedback on the event. We hope to have this feature released later this month. You can follow our progress on this over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/pbrbGrft/107-entry-view-edit-links).